# sympy: test subexpression for trig function

Tags: sympy

I am trying to test whether any sub-expression contains a sin function (or any trig function)

```
from sympy import sin, symbols, Wild
A, B, x, y = symbols('A, B, x, y')
W1=Wild('W1')
```

I can do this:

```
>> (A*sin(x)+B*sin(y)).has(sin(x))
out: True
```

But this does not work:

```
>>: (A*sin(x)+B*sin(y)).has(sin(W1))
out: False
```

How do I test for one or more sin functions regardless of argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Wild`s, use `find`:

```
In [11]: (A*sin(x)+B*sin(y)).find(sin(W1))
Out[11]: set([sin(x), sin(y)])
```

But if you are searching for a single function like sin, and not generic expressions, an easier and faster way is to use `atoms`:

```
In [12]: (A*sin(x)+B*sin(y)).atoms(sin)
Out[12]: set([sin(x), sin(y)])
```

If you want to check for multiple trig functions, `atoms` takes multiple arguments, which is more efficient than calling it multiple times

```
In [14]: (A*sin(x)+B*cos(y)).atoms(sin, cos)
Out[14]: set([sin(x), cos(y)])
```

Comment: Apparently, the "has" method works in a similar manner, but returns logical True/False.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you could pass a class to `has`. In that case, use `expr.has(sin)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my first attempt, I tried to test for sin using a wild card for an argument

```
>>: (A*sin(x)+B*sin(y)).has(sin(W1))
out: False
```

After reading asmeuer's answer and experimenting a bit, I discovered that you can simply pass the class sin (no argument) and it works:

```
>>: (A*sin(x)+B*sin(y)).has(sin, cos)
out: True
```

Thus, use **has** if you want a logical test and use **atoms** if you want a set of the functions that appear in the expression.

Question: is there a general class I can use to test for the presence of any trig function (sin, cos, tan, atan, ...)?